# JobLauncherTestUtils expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: java, junit, spring-batch

i am trying to get my Junit Testcase working. The actual batch is ok. But in future i want to tdd my apps. So i started with junit und spring-batch and came up with the following code. but i am running in an error.

Here is my @EnableBatchConfiguration Class from under test.

```
package de.securess.batch.mail.config;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class BatchMailAppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Bean
    public Step step0() {
        Step step = steps.get("step0")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("JB: Step0 with chunkContex");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
        return step;
    }

    @Bean Job job() {
        System.out.println("JB: job started ...");
        Job job = jobs.get("job")
                .start(step0())
                .build();

        return job;

    }
}
```

And here is my test class:

```
package de.securess.batch.mail;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.batch.core.ExitStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {de.securess.batch.mail.SpringBatchMailApplication.class,de.securess.batch.mail.config.BatchMailAppConfig.class})
public class SpringBatchMailApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Bean 
    public JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils() {
        return new JobLauncherTestUtils();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        JobExecution jobExecution = this.jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
        assertEquals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getExitStatus());   
    }

}
```

And here comes the error code:

```
2018-08-01 17:14:47.988 ERROR 16804 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@4976085] to prepare test instance [de.securess.batch.mail.SpringBatchMailApplicationTests@43c57161]

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'de.securess.batch.mail.SpringBatchMailApplicationTests': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jobLauncherTestUtils'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:393) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118) ~[spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1506) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `JobLauncherTestUtils` is not provided by default in the test execution context. You need to create it and declare it as a bean in your test context. Here is an example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-test/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/test/StepScopeAnnotatedListenerIntegrationTests.java#L98-L101

In the upcoming version 4.1, we added a new annotation `@SpringBatchTest` that adds it to the test context. You can find more details about it here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/testing.html#creatingUnitTestClass . It is already available in version 4.1.0.M2

Comment: Hello Mahmoud,
Can you give me a code example on how to initialize the JobLauncherTestUtils-Bean. What i tried you find appended to the Question.

Comment: In your example, the `JobLauncherTestUtils` is declared as a bean in the test class. You need to declare it in one of the configuration classes imported by the test (`BatchMailAppConfig` or `SpringBatchMailApplication`) and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

For Spring-batch below version 4.1.x . this is how we can manually create `JobLauncherTestUtils`

```
@Bean
     public JobLauncherTestUtils getJobLauncherTestUtils(){

            return new JobLauncherTestUtils() {
                @Override
                @Autowired
                public void setJob(@Qualifier("myjobname") Job job) {
                    super.setJob(job);
                }
            };
        }
```